# How to send a mail with a URL with swaks?

Tags: email, sendmail, gmail, mailbox

**How to send mails with URL with `swaks`. For instance, how would you to send the following mail?**

> [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)

I tried without sucess

```
swaks -t recipient@mail.com \
--body link<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page>
```

Since it is what appear if we display the message as a raw message.

Comment: You need to do more than that to send HTML email. http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/faq.html#send_html_email

Answer (score 6):

The email without the mime headers would come across as plain text. The mime headers make the message body gets seen as HTML.

```
swaks --body '<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">link</a>' - --add-header "MIME-Version: 1.0" --add-header "Content-Type: text/html" -t recipient@mail.com
```

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the problem?

Comment: @chicks the email without the mime headers would come across as plain text, The mime headers make the message body get seen as HTML.